# What is the difference between Intense Rainbow dye and normal rainbow dye?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have searched the web for the answer but I can't seem to find an answer.

Can someone please tell me the difference?

Comment: one is more intense....

Answer (score 2):

The Intense Rainbow Dye seems to produce a more [saturated](http://www.greatreality.com/color/ColorHVC.htm) colour effect than the normal rainbow dye. This means that the intense dye appears brighter, richer and fuller. This is true for all variations of Intense dyes and not just for rainbow dyes.

Below are pictures of me wearing the creeper outfit with rainbow dyes. In the first picture, the head has the vibrant rainbow dye while the chest has the normal dye. The next picture has the two dyes are reversed:

[image: vibrant head normal chest]        [image: vibrant chest normal head]

Comment: This goes for all dyes that have a standard and intense version. Like the intense red/blue/green flame dyes

Answer (score 1):

If the data in the wiki is correct, it appears that [Intense Rainbow Dye](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/File:Intense_Rainbow_Dye_applied.jpg) is simply a brighter (more vibrant) variant of [Rainbow Dye](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/File:Rainbow_Dye_applied.jpg) (these links show the dye applied to a player's clothing). That said, the visual difference appears to be very minor. Intense rainbow dye can be crafted from two rainbow dye.

Comment: As it is for every other colour. In most cases, this only has an effect based off the material. Some material (bricks IIRC) do not display the 'dull' colour very well, and you will need the intense version for it to display clearly.